# Very new to NLP; Chatterbot isn't installing on Anaconda or Colab, and to my knowledge it's not a syntax or version error. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, installation, nlp, google-colaboratory, chatterbot

I am trying to install Chatterbot on Colab or Anaconda (Colab is preferred), but I get the same error both times.

This is my code in Colab:

`!pip install chatterbot`

With this error message:

```
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

On Anaconda Prompts, I have tried:

`pip install chatterbot`

With a result of:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for preshed, thinc, blis, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

`conda install chatterbot` does not work either.

How can I resolve this? I apologize for the simple question, I am very new to NLP.

Comment: unfortunately `chatterbot` only supports `Python >=3.4, <=3.8` whereas in Colab you're getting `Python 3.10.12`. Hence you're facing error with installing `chatterbot`